# Can't Reshape Numpy Array, even with multiple methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am getting a very strange error:

```
print(np.asarray(X[i%len(y)]).shape)
x_train = X[i%len(y)]
x_train.shape = (1, x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1]) 

(39, 4096)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/train_new.py", line 172, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=len(y), epochs=1, verbose=1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 181, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 709, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 685, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I have tried expand_dims, tried np.new_axis, tried reshape to just change the shape of the array to (1, 39, 4096) instead of (39, 4096), and everything gives the same error. Even tried copying the array entry to the variable, still the same erorr.

Why is the error happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is obviously not the complete code, since the error occurs in the not shown `model.fit_generator` call. Please show all the relevant code.

Comment: is `x_train` a `ndarray` or a `keras` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reshape` not `shape`:

```
arr = np.zeros((39, 4096))
dim1, dim2 = arr.shape
arr.reshape((1,dim1,dim2)).shape
(1, 39, 4096)
```

Comment: no still getting the same error ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: @Rafael You can always assign your values. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Rafael The error is complaining that your `train_generator` is generating inconsistent size of data. You must specify which dim can vary to your keras model.